# Create a new PSIClass with Generic type parameters

Tags: intellij-plugin

Newbie question on IntelliJ plugin development.

I need to generate a parameterised class (Class with generics) given the name of the class and the name of the type parameter, but I can not find how to?

It seems PSIClass does not support generics.

**Example**

Given

```
String className = "MyClass";
String typeName = "T"
```

I would like to have a PSIClass that represents this:

```
public class MyClass<T> { ... }
```

The goal is to dynamically add methods to such class and eventually write the complete class to a file. The class needs to declare the Type Variable  because some methods will receive/return T

Thanks!

Comment: `PsiClass` extends `PsiTypeParameterListOwner`, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: `PsiTypeParameterListOwner` has methods to access the type parameters, but how can I create a `PsiTypeParametrListOwner` ?

Comment: Well it's hard to tell what you really need. Do you need to create a new file containing that class, or do you specifically need to have an instance of `PsiClass`? Could you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: Sure, I have edited a bit the problem description. Basically I want a PsiClass which I can then add methods and eventually write it to a file. The class needs to declare the Type Variable "T" because some methods will receive/return T. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in the intelliJ developer forums. It doesn't seem to be the neatest one, but it works.

> I'd recommend to use
>   PsiFileFactory.getInstance(...).createFileFromText("ClassName.java",
>   JavaFileType.INSTANCE, "class ClassName { ...}"), cast the result
>   to PsiJavaFile and use its getClasses[0] as the result.

Here is the link to the thread:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000089970-Create-a-new-PSIClass-with-Generic-type-parameters?page=1#community_comment_115000122164